# How to run a function 1 minute after the mousemove event?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function after the last mousemove event. I've tried the code below:

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['event'])
   eventHandler(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
     // do something
    }, 60000);
   }
```

The problem is, it fires in the first mousemove event and won't reset the time if another event occurs. How to reset it and start the `setTimeout` function each time the event occurs?

Comment: Can you not just unbind and then rebind the event?

Comment: Well you would have to use `clearTimeout` to clear your already existing timeout, and then add a new one … Or you do this the other way around, and have a function called in an interval instead, maybe every second - and have that check the difference between the current timestamp and that of the last mouse move event, and only perform further action if that is > 1 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which framework you're using, but in general you need to store the Id of the timer and cancel it every time and start a new one - remembering to capture the Id.

```js
var timerId = 0

document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("5 seconds since last mouse move");
  },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you call `setTimeout`, the return value is a number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the `clearTimeout()` method to cancel the timer and set it again when a new event occurs. You can read more about [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) here and here.

Basically you can have something like:

```
//global variable
var timeoutID;

[...]

@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['event'])
   eventHandler(event) {
    if (timeoutID)
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
     // do something
    }, 60000);
}
```

I provided a simple jsfiddle (pure js, no framework) too:

```js
var timeoutValue = 2000;
var timeoutID;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  if (timeoutID)
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);

  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(timeoutValue + " just passed");
  }, 2000);
});
```

Cheers!